How can I disable mobile hotspot in Windows 10 for all users except 1 or 2 users?
I want to enable mobile hotspots for a shared computer for only specific users.
I want a certain user to be able to use it while others have it disabled. I know a way to disable this with Group Policy and with reg but am looking for any other way this can be done smoothly without having to log into admin accounts and disable when the other user comes.
Any suggestions are welcome, even programmatic ones I can work with them.
Maybe something to note, the machine has no AD logins.

A group policy is the best way to handle this.  You can apply group policies to user groups.

@Ramhound sorry i made a mistake, the computer is not on a domain. so in Local Group policy the only thing I can find is in network but this is for all users prohibiting internet connection sharing. do you know another way of doing this?

I would allow connecting to a wireless network, but manage access from the other side in some way. Like a proxy server, or wifi authentication.

@LPChip, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. It's one computer connected to the network with an ethernet cable. Now, some people use it as a mobile hotspot. I want all those in that account not to be able to, but someone else in a different account to have the possibility to do so without having to log into admin and disable and enable the LGP

Oh, you mean the reverse. I see... Then my idea won't work indeed.
